# Problem with hyphenation in Ubuntu ( No hyphenation patterns were preloaded for french babel)

Tags: babel, hyphenation, french, babel-french

I have a problem when compiling a latex document in Ubuntu (18.04). I am using TeXmaker et MikTeX. The message is

`Package babel Warning: No hyphenation patterns were preloaded for
(babel) the language French into the format.`

In fact, compiling takes place but the resulting document does not respect the rules of (French) hyphenation at all. So this results in a weird looking document. I have tried many workarounds found here and elsewhere but did't manage to solve the problem. Below an example of (random) French text. (found here https://www.getatext.online/random-french-text-generator). Any ideas how to proceed?

As a side remark, the same file compiles in Windows (with same combination of TeXmaker+MikTeX) without any issue issue being encountered.

```
   \documentclass[11pt,a4paper,french]{article}

    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{times}
    \usepackage{tgtermes}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[french]{babel}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}

    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{5pt plus 2pt minus 1 pt}
    \topmargin  -12mm
    \evensidemargin 5mm
    \oddsidemargin  0mm
    \textwidth  158mm
    \textheight 245mm
    \headheight 14pt
    \headsep 1.2cm


    \begin{document}

   D’y remplie retard contemple près ou durer tour c'est déplacer. Ils gens neiger savourer demander ils remplie donc croissants victor d’y ici. Souvent julie peu professeur basilique maintenant. Beaucoup roman indique tables. Pas paradis. Ascenseurs studio victor enfant puis ma garnier quartier moi bon ou prête. Jour était magasins métiers ruelles. Il du comme mes basilique quasimodo au serait-il grandes victor. Avoir Jour promène termine nous m'en m’encourageaient l'itinéraire s’il visitant luxe. Sa tour quoi bon réservation français tempête petit-déjeuner merci grandes du. Criminels N'est-ce madame la. Qu'on dieu est. Étages une.

Voir tables encore découvrais. Peine paris cœur rêvait pizzas disponible 30 criminels avec dans. Ce l'île. Nous on excusez-moi fois. Je aider pourtant quel ruelles tableaux comme pour attend. Peine pour changer gentils. Glace pluie plats marche. Suis français neiger puissiez petites vent du m'en enseigner parce justice. Va attendre magasins le minutes observer gris professeur. Monde plats petites parler. L'ambiance quatre qu’il tempête apprécier aura. Plein remplie avec réservation. Montrerai film. Pied temps penser voulez. Grand risque l'art semaine.

Les Dentiste voulais bon mais. Repas d'à produits occuper crains peut prête croissants ainsi. Pour savoir film repas arc-en-ciel sommes 21h neige pied occuper café. Voir basse tempête carrière avoir pour j'étais suis soigner costume pluie. Aujourd'hui capitale brouillard. Champs-Élysées Aussi disponible préfère neiger brouillard l'arc appellera on. Infirmières montmartre calme pompier aider température dans défendre temps nôtre malades contemple. C'est 21h chaque neige. Mathématiques le s’il j'avais monter aux glace excusez-moi puissiez chez l'itinéraire 30. Bon village l'île camille délicieux éclair découvrais ma si. Triomphe si. Pense m'en professeur pleuvoir alors étages visiter enseigner ainsi encore observer. Est vais risque température pierre jour n'est-ce avec.

D'à sont on excusez-moi foudre. Triomphe visitant savourer madame tuileries pense. J'étais tard temps tranquille maintenant. Tables j’ai sommes. Encore commence j’ai éclair apprécier n'aimait penser beaucoup. Soir l'île grêle soleil nuages beaucoup chaud monter. Près température ici l'ambiance m'appelle sans. Triomphe fera encore l'art. Jours combattre puis-je quand ainsi d'avocat choisir cité fort. Cité aujourd'hui grandes qu’il avec en votre est andrew venir tour. Ascenseurs criminels demander 21h il professeur jour étages notre-dame. Fonctionne disais ma petites possible pourtant je de le en congélation. Donné pluie très occupés bon sur contemple. Village ceux montmartre costume n'est-ce. Tableaux tombe plein magasins.

Carte commence. Maintenant pourtant volontaire étages occuper j'étais lycéen journée. Encore héros luxe frites l'ambiance sera d'être poursuivre. Désolé paradis possible cité marques une. Policier serveur pied. Ascenseurs justice film sans visitant costume capitale sera pierre par d'à champs-élysées. En était demander. Quasimodo monter retard. Dans eiffel personnage bon paris notre-dame plats arc-en-ciel. Disais sommes rêves passion parce paradis près maintenant. Ils pompier tuileries découvrais mais j'étais d'être changer défendre carte petits. Nuages Docteur une s’il enfin mathématiques marques professeur chez. Du tranquille quasimodo avec docteur réservation l'itinéraire pied la. Fera découvrais quasimodo réellement quasimodo s’il mon observer neige.

Soit risques serveur pied. De observer. Peine n'est-ce le plein tous fatiguée. Notre-Dame le soit m’encourageaient au se pizzas j'avais longtemps si gris. Basilique l'après-midi mon hugo. Enseigner quartier calmer je pour tuileries. Ça julie puis rêves disais repas carrière grêle qu'un désolé docteur quartier. Ça merci criminels 30 sommes criminels remplie puissiez d’y foudre arc-en-ciel pourrez. Remplie devenir chez sommes fort minutes possible donc m'appelle j'étais me avec. Grêle notre-dame manger eiffel ou. Crient aider possible arc-en-ciel ici ruelles doute visitant camille devenir lycéen ils. Chaud personnage serait-il encore fier le. Éclair des monde nuages pizzas moi ils neige. Par ascenseurs votre. Commence médecins lendemain d'être vous leur était pompier monter toujours.

Petit-déjeuner pompier congélation demander. Température victor tous qu’il. Basilique l'arc m'appelle. Température près enfin ami être manger moi pensait. Ce une justice héros votre sur parler merci. Sont découvrais savourer moi. Docteur parents métro les peins. Qu’il attendre on je andrew profiter s’il promène. D'être eiffel attendre ainsi chef. Les ceux appellera visitant a-t-il ça. Carte doute suis. Eiffel vue tour sapeur-pompier après tombe calmer personnage météo ceux prête penser. Peins l'après-midi savourer très. Table quartier parler par soigner leur puis-je attend splendide 30 était fonctionne. Camille fort.

Pleuvoir Petits Quartier l'ambiance village parents manger. Durer alors réellement. Venir Maintenant était vais va. Fatiguée aura gris parents gris pour. Triomphe puis d’y l'arc semaine triomphe côté tour plein restaurant j'étais victor. Vous m’encourageaient excusez-moi qu'il pourtant pourrez roman. Apprécier chaque risque savoir artiste tableaux avec. Détestait Plats Lorsqu’il je parents il vue ou soleil. Table désolé il soigner table pense criminels possible tard soir. Rêvait nuages façade grand on justice crient.

Victor encore quand sommes sans qu'il nom ruelles. Quartier souvent minutes c'est. Crient vent frites aider c’est côté professeur. Venir aller alors triomphe. Bonsoir de pensait sera fois capitale. Quoi termine basilique et m'en savourer julie puis va avec étages. M’encourageaient produits contemple. Possible après l'après-midi victor ses serveur. Tables attend choisir victor lycéen combattre il vent français tonnerre petits manger. Pas tranquille votre personnage région très préfère arc-en-ciel. Parlent et l'art parents pied qu'un dans grande petits. Cathédrale N'est-ce enfant pierre calmer et préfère fait. Luxe venir monde. Cathédrale et soir puissiez.

Pas peux donné en contemple beaux. Désolé andrew tranquille leur carrière grandes nuages. Pense sera réservation observer au voulez mon tonnerre mon brouillard montmartre il. Artiste ruelles. Aussi donc près dentiste sommet combattre. Fera l'arc nom au visitant détestait. Était frites dieu neiger. Beaucoup minutes champs-élysées ami ici thomas délicieux grande pense durer grande. N'est-ce grandes qu’il longtemps fera nous n'aimait studio fort grêle chaque. Neige promène enfant se français produits occuper commence ma docteur dans votre. Venir sapeur-pompier pizzas pleurait rues aux excusez-moi a-t-il voir découvrais. Sur ruelles ne triomphe votre tour. Savourer savourer plus. L'Arc cœur village longtemps. Combattre d'avocat pourrez quartier les l'ambiance chez dentiste l'ambiance métiers en.

Plein avec pleurait peu enfin nôtre parents semaine excusez-moi nuages changer. Excusez-moi enfin sommes tous tonnerre gentils triomphe monter. Beaux problème qu'un café jour qu’il. Éclair j'étais des. Docteur et encore carrière aujourd'hui température foudre retard soit ruelles. Bien lendemain basse n'ai pourtant prête pensait pompier. Qu'un crains carte rues ceux disponible vous excusez-moi pouvait sommes disponible près. Quoi croissants éclair jour. Beaux attend. L'Opéra en journée costume après encore. Prête prendre notre-dame fort tables nôtre sera sur sera. Aussi notre pizzas champs-élysées j’ai. De réservation sa par contemple ça thomas vérifier. Pourtant peut ceux pleuvoir. Andrew longtemps tous.

Pas vous disais mathématiques mais mathématiques fait fort 30. Je c’est vous studio ici risques infirmières excusez-moi. Pluie dans occupés. D’y Ce ça appellera combattre. Thomas c'est choisir devenir excusez-moi maintenant village. Et désolé fort gens votre il l'île l'itinéraire criminels une andrew rêvait. Tombe notre-dame rues aider tour lui puis qu'il voir semaine. Garnier ça sont restaurant éclair policier d’y. Puissiez serveur avoir me. C'est petits c'est. Retard cantine arc-en-ciel sur excusez-moi puis-je lendemain mon d’y café. Petit-déjeuner madame tables vent. Sera désolé tableaux. Nôtre médecins.

Marche serveur il ça grandes maintenant avec parlent réservation justice frites. Indique arc-en-ciel marques crains quatre camille. Occuper penser aider changer ce semaine quartier. Journée magasins lycéen cette madame température. Qu'on il mon criminels savourer chez personnage. Ils en justice pour il bar. Neige soit fera rues professeur qu'un fera avec m'appelle l'art m'entends. Appellera Sans pourtant petites quasimodo. Infirmières l'arc déplacer carrière peux venir encore lui grande. Produits l'art risques. Et croissants m'appelle pierre d’y madame serveur. Paradis grande gris comme ce ascenseurs 21h notre-dame carte plein si parents. Ma ils montmartre d'être sa. Montrerai champs-élysées semaine.

Soigner risques garnier. Qui quartier risque réservation mathématiques contemple lendemain ou changer visiter prêt. Carte aux doute marques tempête professeur pied n'est-ce village fort serait-il avec. Beaucoup d’y fort attendre ou hugo éclair d'à de jour l'arc. Côté métiers eiffel région quatre la village qu'on était savourer pour plein. Justice ici tonnerre verdure disponible. De tombe prendre produits carrière lendemain l'arc nôtre qu'il avoir. Dentiste Termine combattre. M'appelle gentils l'itinéraire pour disponible splendide occuper serveur sa. Vent Tempête studio luxe quel changer prendre ça prendre puis-je. Au très pouvait vous disais ma qui grand. Lui Toujours visitant parents l'île quoi fera c'est était occupés puis-je vent.

Pour tranquille peu cathédrale s’il fois marques choisir camille. Aux risques rues foudre. Ruelles excusez-moi grand savourer. Mais tous lorsqu’il façade tranquille pizzas. Il quatre découvrais peux. Montmartre rêves déplacer qu'on c'est si garnier marques l'arc mon grand tranquille. Aller quand. Pense criminels enseigner tuileries va voir plein savoir éclair nuages avec lendemain. Va risques apprécier. L'Arc C'est avoir sans il criminels réservation m’encourageaient. Produits fier rues n'aimait calmer avec occupés. Promène personnage petits éclair. Temps vérifier m'appelle mais tableaux si victor disponible. Bar prêt possible risque qui.

Gens crient infirmières merci. Gens d'attente j'étais pourrez occupés profiter qu'il ainsi apprécier n'aimait tempête glace. Passion encore avoir pluie l'opéra. Et de. Problème réservation foudre est paradis. Durer j’ai aura bon excusez-moi d’y termine quatre il nuages l'ambiance comme. Très découvrais termine. Fier fera voir capitale mes. Montrerai ils ça soigner pouvait cité détestait andrew combattre grandes fatiguée. Montmartre quatre peine pouvait aussi être vous termine voir tuileries. Je monter fort victor suis qu'on délicieux est on ami et après. Rêvait visiter smith risque. Soit on paradis marche changer souvent pompier tombe paris puis-je n'est-ce l'après-midi. Plats ne héros j’ai visitant qu'il. Pluie carrière peins pour calme qu'on température tard savourer ses.

Visiter apprécier la sa notre. Il Aller gens dentiste va ceux brouillard frites. Le n'aimait gens attendre vérifier on visiter. Crient remplie sur. Costume Pluie occuper pour savourer personnage serait-il dans ses encore malades grandes. Enfant quel infirmières smith ça quatre lui. Je sapeur-pompier. Sans médecins l'arc avec mes tous. Réservation artiste. Métro longtemps disponible possible devenir prendre volontaire. Fait plus attendre avoir défendre français cœur. Sont délicieux glace l'ambiance tables. Sans lorsqu’il peine grêle une c’est l'ambiance.

Parler d'être donné n'est-ce on petites soleil en aller venir. Le je calmer peut l'île c'est professeur tête merci éclair serveur apprécier. Plein prêt bar monter tard quand parents aider encore alors parents. N'aimait pied rues quand. Éclair cité vais détestait fonctionne après donné arc-en-ciel avec luxe beaucoup. Neiger merci peins peine roman. Soir pas préfère nom. Calmer après quartier chez monter criminels. Tableaux artiste va si visitant quand mon journée. D'avocat pensait pluie. Voulais marche criminels cuisinier fera notre-dame réservation votre beaucoup pierre. Bonsoir grande. Changer étages météo mathématiques j'avais vent sapeur-pompier quel soigner. D'à produits voir marche carte crient prête désolé côté paradis disponible longtemps. Plus en l'arc bon arc-en-ciel.

Profiter prendre ses roman ascenseurs venir n'ai. Chaud luxe observer plein aller visiter monter me. D'attente vent sera le cathédrale un table des en. Serveur ami petites gris. Pourrez hugo basilique nom délicieux petites. Métro sommet prête plein serait-il minutes. Eiffel Petit-déjeuner tombe infirmières monde jour combattre vérifier vais peine. Ainsi artiste. Plus nom retard victor qu'il. Fera je attend découvrais. Monter attend éclair excusez-moi problème quand carrière l'arc température l'arc après. Puissiez Façade longtemps ses vent français plein météo prêt petites ils. Chez sur vent quel découvrais.

Préfère qu'il gentils par carte aider tableaux réservation. Venir nom le il paris capitale il journée adolescent carte 21h ses. C'est voulais fait l'art fort réellement penser table longtemps bien et il. Crains d'avocat m’encourageaient. 21h jour thomas m'entends petits. Sa quand excusez-moi en 30 délicieux je aider verdure avoir. Tête héros bon risque brouillard savoir aujourd'hui quand film victor. Réellement cuisinier soigner quoi encore. Que région tard personnage tombe soit sera. Qu'il sommes jour brouillard venir nuages tard termine français beaux. Toujours Petits rêves préfère lui repas de madame pierre n'ai victor. Près fatiguée poursuivre puissiez beaucoup région. Ma tous village apprécier qu’il. Film plein temps volontaire.

Julie tonnerre notre-dame héros savoir bar bonsoir d’y fois. Tables aux excusez-moi mais désolé. M'entends temps je plein moi que. Sur pizzas studio l'après-midi. Quatre Adolescent m'en soit j’ai avec roman. Quand très. Semaine village par profiter ruelles croissants calmer sans monde. Le verdure champs-élysées maintenant réservation qui. Excusez-moi vérifier la pour puis-je tard ou cuisinier. Ainsi sa smith parler une plats soleil. Tous n'ai n'ai table capitale du camille moi après ce. Tranquille docteur l'itinéraire pierre temps. Parler magasins qu'il magasins préfère ça c'est merci est. Grandes l'arc quand congélation c’est visitant calme donc météo.

Étages il en attend. Rêvait Cette durer adolescent. Me pense encore c'est d'avocat une ce tombe basse souvent cantine tombe. Rues lui pleurait bon l'itinéraire cité quatre policier triomphe parlent tour pensait. Contemple manger. Jour d’y grandes champs-élysées ce avec qui l'arc. Sera grêle ascenseurs. Qu'on contemple. Déplacer Fait et c'est météo. Aller ma justice personnage c’est serveur. Tard quand j'étais peut. Aussi tour fatiguée lui vent au et. Qui après semaine jour doute alors cathédrale retard quatre serait-il arc-en-ciel.

Visiter voulais congélation puis voulez excusez-moi 30 ou déplacer si. Semaine Glace Peins détestait tranquille ses fort aider détestait leur voir. Réellement quand ici contemple mon cité. Pleuvoir Dentiste smith. Parler m’encourageaient sapeur-pompier. Devenir passion région être. Qu'il marques enfant. Serveur garnier donné mes avec frites grêle nous. Neiger hugo. Fier m'entends mon calme d'à cathédrale luxe. N'est-ce Tour qu'un policier c'est déplacer il pleurait.

Calmer disponible petites fort qu'il le va très gentils d'être. Cité n'aimait attend quel tableaux. Région doute qu'un pied fera. Beaucoup aussi venir criminels cathédrale camille de longtemps tonnerre excusez-moi. Montrerai fois. Lorsqu’il sur. Nom vérifier choisir alors quatre arc-en-ciel des fier roman personnage. Lendemain encore champs-élysées savourer ou. M’encourageaient notre sommet cantine. Maintenant jour. C'est soigner ami l'opéra défendre lycéen éclair tables problème pied. Après dentiste splendide doute commence pluie brouillard. Chez nous donné verdure crient. Adolescent peu. Jours possible mes soit pompier vue criminels retard qu’il andrew bonsoir soigner.

Détestait croissants avoir demander vue venir café l'art pouvait poursuivre. Avec aux occuper croissants observer m’encourageaient. Julie Restaurant artiste l'île cité appellera médecins pense minutes peine voir. Fait la parler excusez-moi visitant mais. Suis moi ce monter. Cité il promène beaucoup près en volontaire pour bon. Pierre l'opéra fatiguée tableaux s’il. Fort la a-t-il nôtre en occupés film avec commence vous. Tour retard a-t-il arc-en-ciel contemple j'étais nuages policier. Délicieux grêle c'est avoir bon. Fera temps la andrew quel pour il tempête mais français voulez pas. N'ai puissiez. Moi ascenseurs préfère adolescent puis-je. Eiffel voulez pourtant peut.

Durer en problème bien prévisions m'entends. Justice si thomas. Enseigner soleil restaurant il quand quel votre basilique tableaux et. Ses village tard. Crains mais personnage bon. Température sans frites dans bon. Pleuvoir la héros soigner temps qu’il étages le grandes disais possible. Les temps d'avocat ses. Aura serveur ceux tables durer pour beaux lorsqu’il café je durer. Météo durer luxe m'en et jours dans policier. Météo merci tête devenir tonnerre découvrais. Attend remplie m'en ami paris pleuvoir. Peut pleuvoir paradis moi ascenseurs ascenseurs paradis. Découvrais monter ça manger infirmières petites. Artiste eiffel et il soir petit-déjeuner parce moi température chez m'entends disais.

Mais termine quand foudre découvrais prévisions serveur risques bonsoir. Une hugo grandes je encore je jours calme magasins c’est tuileries basilique. Arc-en-ciel bonsoir vérifier. Détestait délicieux sommes produits peu garnier si. Parlent dieu petites quasimodo visitant leur tonnerre. Magasins adolescent chef policier attendre ruelles je foudre minutes montrerai serveur. Manger observer métro fonctionne savoir fois qu’il visiter dieu. Dieu métro soleil qui peux. Sera risque sa venir temps. Sommet luxe foudre. Souvent beaucoup votre journée produits garnier tard après minutes choisir soleil. J'étais ici rues. Nuages petits métiers encore fatiguée monter artiste j’ai passion bar. Basse Thomas je chaque en produits sera.

Au mes savoir cantine dentiste crient. Maintenant soit la cité a-t-il ça restaurant je thomas ascenseurs ça. Découvrais grande bar toujours vais changer. Désolé sommet ils. Observer contemple façade enseigner être. L'art attend tableaux bien soit d'à artiste la. Basilique me chef éclair basse. Chef quartier madame encore peux. Professeur sont. Crains parlent sa d'attente quoi. C'est semaine pourrez beaucoup pouvait grande. Parce lycéen marques quel produits m’encourageaient tard victor peine calmer désolé. Était triomphe chef carte notre-dame fois verdure gens film chez. Penser luxe aux un très réellement repas qu'on cathédrale grandes. Français tard crains n'aimait sera médecins n'est-ce le studio brouillard cœur.

Magasins madame du marques attendre julie tête bar grand jours n'ai vous. Va andrew sans n'aimait aujourd'hui neige ici soigner prêt minutes malades près. Vérifier m'en est tonnerre. Bien cœur profiter. Si petites doute splendide. Rêvait gris cantine déplacer après marques donc observer. Voulez nom choisir durer arc-en-ciel journée quand neiger. Repas Fera contemple leur tour pour promène ne m'entends si cuisinier. Montrerai peine préfère tempête n'aimait plein prête la jours. Pensait grêle carrière d’y aller durer. Neige criminels français. Contemple mon disponible bien. Après Ce 21h frites bien sont attend plein.

Contemple monde mais peine. Éclair pas notre gentils vue tranquille croissants peux prévisions. Tonnerre bar disponible petits vous excusez-moi prévisions de comme beaux. Dentiste garnier longtemps d'attente aussi. Andrew merci jour café policier film café des. Ou policier parents tranquille combattre d'attente pleurait. Cantine marques prête toujours tempête magasins docteur fort. Foudre a-t-il peine pluie risque. Nôtre est soigner ascenseurs arc-en-ciel peut restaurant restaurant. Jours monde peine délicieux peux tranquille cœur disponible. Professeur lui. Changer d'à très fier produits magasins eiffel beaux héros infirmières parler costume. Après sans mon calmer quatre. Qui termine ruelles pour remplie brouillard pas peine beaucoup m'entends m'entends. Pour risques pompier apprécier policier visiter victor occupés l'arc.

   \end{document}
```

MikTeX language settings

[image]

Comment: Check in the miktex console, in settings / languages if french is installed and activated.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It is check but the installed column is empty. See update.

Comment: check in the package tab if hyph-utf8 is installed.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer No, I am installing it right now!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you very much. It solved the problem! Strangely, I didn't find with googling a similar workaround.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have not hyph-utf8 installed. Install it through the package manager.